# P-8A Poseidon Airfoil type

Tags: boeing-737, airfoil, boeing

Could someone help me find out what airfoil type is used on the P-8A Poseidon symmetrical, conventional, thin or supercritical airfoil?

It seems to be, that the Boeing 737-800, like many commercial jetliners, uses a type of airfoil known as a supercritical airfoil. But I would think the P-8A Poseidon might have a symmetrical one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you think it might have a symmetrical section?

You need to decide whether you're interested in the airfoils on the wing, the vertical tail, or the horizontal tail.  These are unlikely to be the same.  Also, the surfaces likely use multiple foils.

The vertical tail airfoils are likely symmetrical.

The horizontal tail and wing airfoils are not going to be symmetrical.

There are symmetrical supercritical airfoils.

Answer (score 2):

I know that in [Dave Lednicers brilliant website](https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/aircraft.html#conventional) the P-3 is listed with the NACA 0014 and 0012 airfoils. But that does not mean that a symmetrical airfoil is the best choice for a maritime surveillance airplane. Far from it!

The wing of the P-8A is based on that of the Boeing 737-900, and you can be sure that the airfoil is the same. Any change would result in a costly re-certification which the new ex-McDonnell-Douglas management of Boeing will surely avoid like the plague.

The airfoil of the original 737 series [was conventional](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/87191/why-doesnt-boeing-use-supercritical-airfoils) and modified to bring it to a [somewhat supercritical shape](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33025/was-the-737-300s-wing-an-early-supercritical-wing/33031#33031) with the introduction of the classic series (737-300 etc.). Further improvements followed with the redesigned wing of the next generation (737-600 etc.), so that the current 737 models sport a modern supercritical airfoil (which is company-proprietary, of course).